# Java - Help on using "split()"

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to write a code in java that functions similar to the "split()" command in Java, but does not remove the parts that match the regex. For example:

```
String str = "ABC---DEF***GHI///JKL#@!";
```

Then

```
`str.split("[A-Za-z0-9]+")` returns `{"---", "***", "///", "#@!"}`.
```

However, I want to write a method similar to `split()` that splits the string AT matches of the regex, rather than AROUND it.

```
`An example of an implementaion would be: 
public static String[] splitString(String input, String regex)`
```

Thus:

```
`splitString("ABC---123DEF***456GHI///JKL9#@6!", "[A-Za-z0-9]+")`
```

would give:

```
`{"ABC", "---", "123DEF", "***", "456GHI", "///", "JKL9", "#@", "6", "!"}`
```

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: So You want to have both in a result i.e split result + matched pattern ?

Comment: Please make an effort rather than asking SO to write your code for you.

Comment: Please show us the expected output?

Comment: Worth mentioning that in other languages you can simply use `.split("([A-Za-z0-9]+)")` (with a capturing group), but Java is missing this feature.

Comment: @Sabin Jose - The last line is the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other posters have noted, one way to do this is to use your pattern, then the inverse. This can be accomplished with a single regex, `([A-Za-z0-9]*)([^A-Za-z0-9]*)`

```
String str = "ABC---DEF***GHI///JKL#@!";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]*)([^A-Za-z0-9]*)").matcher(str);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    for(int i=1; i<=m.groupCount(); i++) {
        if(!m.group(i).isEmpty()) {
            result.add(m.group(i));
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(result, ", "));
```

Output:

```
ABC, ---, 123DEF, ***, 456GHI, ///, JKL9, #@, 6, !
```

Comment: You should amend the regex to match also the case "+++ABC---..." (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Use a matcher to find all matches of the regular expression and then build result of the split yourself.

The following method shows where all the matches of a regular expression are:

```
public static void findMatches(String input, String regex)
{
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.printf("%d-%d%n", matcher.start(), matcher.end());
    }
}
```

Now use the indices you find in this way together with `String.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)` to create the string array with the split result you want.

Comment: This is actually a better solution than the ones (mine included) using an inverted regex.

Answer (score 1):

Because of regexp groups are limited, i think, the only way is to split by your_pattern and by ANTY-your_pattern and join results 1 by 1, like so:

ANTY-regex is `[^A-Za-z0-9]+` for you. (^ at the start of [] negate int)

```
public String[] splitString(String input, String regex, String antiRegex)
{
    String[] letters = input.split(regex);
    String[] symbols = input.split(antiRegex);
    String[] result = new String[letters.length + symbols.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = letters[i];
        if (++i < symbols.length) //important: ++i, NOT i++
        {
            result[i] = symbols[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**UPD: there is no check if lettess sequence is first in the input string, so if you need, add id.**

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method to do that using regex and removing the first found match from the original string. I am a bit lazy to write the whole code but in pseudo code it will be something like. You will use two patterns - one for words and one for everything else at start of a string:

```
Pattern literals="(^[A-Za-z0-9]+)";
Pattern everythingElse="(^[^A-Za-z0-9]+)";
List<String> results;

while(str is not finished){
 Matcher literalsMatcher= literals.matcher(str);
 if(literalsMatcher.find()){
   results.add(literalsMatcher.group(1));
   str.subString(0,literalsMatcher.group(1).length();
 }

Matcher everythingElseMatcher = everythingElse.matcher(str);
 if(everythingElseMatcher.find()){
   results.add(everythingElseMatcher.group(1));
   str.subString(0,everythingElseMatcher.group(1).length();
 }
```

}

Something like that. Sorry for the bad code but I think you can get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have recurrent version:

```
  public static String[] split(String msg, String expr){
      if (msg.split(expr).length == 1){
        return msg.split(expr);
      }
      String[] tab = msg.split(expr, 2);
      String exprStr = msg.substring(tab[0].length(),  msg.length() -  tab[1].length());
      int exprLength = msg.length() - tab[0].length() - tab[1].length();
      String[] tab1 = split(msg.substring(tab[0].length() + exprLength, msg.length()), expr);
      String[] result = new String[1 + 1 + tab1.length];
      result[0] = tab[0];
      result[1] = exprStr;
      for (int i = 0; i <  tab1.length;++i){
         result[i + 2] = tab1[i];
      }
      return result;
```

}